# JQuery Find Next item By Class

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a bunch of radio buttons next to text inputs. When a radio button state is changed I run a method that gets all the radio buttons with a class of ".IdPassportRadioButton". For each radio button I want to find the next text input and either enable or disable that input depending on the radio button.

HTML looks as follows:

```
<div class="editor-container" style="">
        <div class="editor-label">
            <%=Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsPassport, false, 
                                        new { @class = "IdPassportRadioButton" })%>
            ID Number
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%=Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.IdentityNumber, 
                                   new { @class = "textbox IdPassportTextBox"})%>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JQuery Method:

```
$(".IdPassportRadioButton").each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).next(".IdPassportTextBox").removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            $(this).next(".IdPassportTextBox").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
    });
```

As you can see I try to find the next TextBox by class ".IdPassportTextBox", But that does not work. Everything works except the line to get the next Textbox.

Any Suggestions

Comment: This is how I would do it -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bbwYx/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**closest()**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) with selector `"editor-container"` to reach the `parent of TextBox` with class IdPassportTextBox and using [**find()**](http://api.jquery.com/find/) with selector `".IdPassportTextBox"` method to access the textbox.

```
$(".IdPassportRadioButton").each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).closest(".editor-container").find(".IdPassportTextBox").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
        $(this).closest(".editor-container").find(".IdPassportTextBox").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
});
```

Comment: You are welcome, updated my answer just for forgot to put dot.

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery '.Parent()' method to get a hold of the enclosing 'editor-container', and then select the 'IdPassportTextbox' out of that.